# How to encode camera frames into mp4 on android

Tags: android, camera, capture, frames, stagefright

I take camera preview frames from android camera in **640x480** (sufficient to me) and do some modifications over them. But now I need to encode those to new `MP4` file (with audio).

Is this some how possible? I can't use `ffmpeg` due to its not so good license, but I've found `Stagefright` framework which should be probably capable of doing that. But I did not find any sort of official documentation or tutorials to do such a thing I need to do.

Is there a way to do it with this framework please? I don't need codes, I would be very glad just for pointing me the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

There is one scenario where the use-case described is realized. Consider a scenario where the `Camera` output is fed to an `OpenGL` library where some effects are applied on the preview frames which need to be recorded.

Well in this case, you can use the traditional `MediaRecorder` with `GrallocSource` instead of `CameraSource`. The setup would look like thus:

`MediaRecorder` is set up with the `GrallocSource`. The input surfaces for recording are provided by the `Camera` + `OpenGL` combined operation which implement a `SurfaceTextureClient`. A good example for this can be found in [`SurfaceMediaSource_test` modules](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/tests/SurfaceMediaSource_test.cpp#736).

Comment: Actually, I have no idea what are you talking about :D But will do some more research to it though. Sounds very interesting, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**stagefright** is quite good if you must support API 9 and higher. But this framework is not official, as you saw. You can use the sample code in [platform/frameworks/av](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/cmds/stagefright) at your risk.

The google source includes CameraSource, which provides the camera frames directly to the encoder. While this approach may be much more efficient (the pixels are not copied to the user space at all), it does not allow manipulation. It is possible to modify the C++ source, but I strongly recommend to access the Camera in Java, and pass the [preview frames](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29) via JNI to stagefrght (OpenMAX) encoder. On some devices, this may force you to use software encoder. You must convert the video frames to YUV planar format for the encoder. See [libyuv](https://code.google.com/p/libyuv/) for optimized converters.

If you can restrict your support to API 16 and higher, it is safer to use the official Java [MediaCdec API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html).

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't restrict to api 16  It has too low marketshare :/ but thanks for sample code  hopefully i'll find something there

Comment: Ok, I just have a many hour research on stagefright and I am pretty lost by now. My goal is to record 480x480 video on API 14+ devices. But I have totally no idea how to do that. I think it is possible to override CameraSource for MediaRecorder to supply with stream I want, or to clip it or whatever. I've looked on JNI, i know how to use my custom native codes in app, but I am totally lost in how to even record video via JNI. What more to record it... Can you please help? Thanks

Comment: I've probably found solution. Only i need is to find method for encoding in android's native sources, then make my jni to call that and pass camera frames. And that is all right?

Comment: Note that the stagefright (OpenMAX) video encoder has a hardware accelerated mode where it can access directly the camera buffers. This is not good for you, because you want to modify (clip) the source. On some devices, this may force you to use software encoder. See [**update**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23453635/192373).

Comment: I intended to do it this way: I catch onPreviewFrame from camera so i get byte[] array of frame. Then i would pass that byte array to my cpp class which would manage encoding it into mp4 file (almost) same way as http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/record.cpp does. This way i would use hw to encode or not?

Comment: Yes, this is the right path, and it is quite likely that the HW encoder will be used.

Comment: @bakua.. Please do note one specific point when you are trying to employ `recordVideo`. If you are passing `YUV` frames through metadata format i.e. `Gralloc` handles, then there could be some issues using the existing code. `recordVideo` runs in the shell process whereas the `HW` accelerated `MediaCodec`/`OMXCodec` runs in `MediaServer` process where the `Gralloc` handle may not be a valid address. Hence, reusing existing `recordVideo` for `metadata` is not very straight forward especially for `HW` codecs.